# How to add a div to single products in woocomerce <ul class="products"/> tag

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to customize the woocomerce shop page.
Therefore I looking for the file which create the li tag in the product ul.

Example:

```
<ul class="products">
<li first post-11 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail     
product_cat-schimmelentferner sale taxable shipping-taxable purchasable  
product-type-simple product-cat-schimmelentferner instock
```

...

Does someone know which files are responsible for this code?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ul-classproducts-populated-from):

```
content-product.php
```